# Singleton Instance Comparison

Tags: c#, singleton

I have a singleton class as follows that I use in models to represent a currency type.

```
public class CurrencyType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public static CurrencyType USD => new CurrencyType(1, "USD", "USD");
    public static CurrencyType EUR => new CurrencyType(2, "EUR", "EUR");
    public static CurrencyType GBP => new CurrencyType(3, "GBP", "GBP");

    public CurrencyType(int value, string name, string text)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
        Text = text;
    }

    public static CurrencyType GetInstance(string name)
    {
        return CurrencyTypes.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }

    public static List<CurrencyType> CurrencyTypes = new List<CurrencyType>
    {
        USD,
        EUR,
        GBP
    };

    public CurrencyType()
    {
    }
}
```

I imagine `CurrencyType.GBP` should exactly be the same as `CurrencyType.GetInstance("GBP")` as it returns `GBP` from the list in the singleton.

However `CurrencyType.GBP == CurrencyType.GetInstance("GBP")` returns false. What is the reason behind this, am I missing a crucial point?

Comment: It's not a singleton. Everytime any of the static properties are called a new instance is created.

Comment: `CurrencyType GBP => ` should be `CurrencyType GBP {get;} => `. Pernicious, I know

Comment: @Charlieface: _"`CurrencyType GBP =>`  should be `CurrencyType GBP {get;} =>`"_ -- not true. The lambda-property syntax omits the `{ get; }`. It is, however, required for read-only _initialized_ properties, e.g. `CurrencyType GBP { get; } = new ...` (i.e. what the OP should have used instead).

Comment: @PeterDuniho is what I was trying to say. Note to self: don't write syntax from memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static CurrencyType USD => new CurrencyType(1, "USD", "USD");
public static CurrencyType EUR => new CurrencyType(2, "EUR", "EUR");
public static CurrencyType GBP => new CurrencyType(3, "GBP", "GBP");
```

**Solution:** Replace "=>" with "=".

**Reason:** "=>" in this case is a short way of property getter property.
Property behind the scenes is a method, which will return always a new instance of CurrencyType when it's called, because of "new" operator.

Comment: _"Replace "=>" with "="."_ -- doing that will result in declaration of _fields_, not properties. Please fix your code example so that it preserves the _read-only property_ nature of the original code.